# Text input field not reflecting "value" after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My webpage contains the following table (generated from PHP/MySQL):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            20126/P1010340 (0)<br>
            <input type='text' id='updater0' size=50 type='text' value='100' onBlur='blurEvent0()'><br>
            <input type='button' id='update0' value ='update' onClick='updateEvent0()'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/20126/P1010340.jpg' width= '300' alt='plaatje'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            20126/P1010343 (1)<br>
            <input type='text' id='updater1' size=50 type='text' value='200' onBlur='blurEvent1()'><br>
            <input type='button' id='update1' value ='update' onClick='updateEvent1()'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/20126/P1010343.jpg' width= '300' alt='plaatje'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            20126/P1010344 (2)<br>
            <input type='text' id='updater2' size=50 type='text' value='300' onBlur='blurEvent2()'><br>
            <input type='button' id='update2' value ='update' onClick='updateEvent2()'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/20126/P1010344.jpg' width= '300' alt='plaatje'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=top>
            20126/P1010345 (3)<br>
            <input type='text' id='updater3' size=50 type='text' value='400' onBlur='blurEvent3()'><br>
            <input type='button' id='update3' value ='update' onClick='updateEvent3()'>
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
</table>
```

Each row shows a text field (regulating the order of the .jpgs, preloaded from the database), a button and a `.jpg`. Pressing the button updates the order parameter (via Ajax and PHP as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060556/javascript-to-update-mysql)). This all works fine, however... if I reload the page to see the effect of the change in the order of the .jpgs (which is correct), the text field in any rows I had altered, still shows the value I had entered previously by hand, and not the new appropriate value from the database. Thus the page source might show (the new value in the database):

```
<input type='text' id='updater2' size=50 type='text' value='350' onBlur='blurEvent2()'>
```

but I see a value of (say) 400 on the actual page. `blurEventX` only changes the background colour for any values changed by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, this only occurs in Firefox, and not in Internet Explorer or Google Chrome. It therefore appears to be a browser issue (bug?) and not a problem with the programming.