# Ajax doesn't connect with database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with `ajax`. I want to make a simple vote system but I have problems with it:

```
<div id="button_up" onclick="vote_plus(1,$id)"></div>
<div id="button_down" onclick="vote_plus(-1,$id)"></div>
```

votesystem.php

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
connection();
$page_id=$_GET['page_id'];
$rate=$_GET['rate'];
mysql_query("UPDATE img SET suma=suma+$rate, ocen=ocen+1 WHERE id=$page_id");

?>
```

and main function:

```
function vote_plus(rate,page_id)
    {   
    alert('rate='+rate+'id='+page_id);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'vote_system.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {rate:rate, page_id:page_id},
      success: function(output) 
      {
          alert('success, server says '+output);
      }, error: function()
      {
          alert('something went wrong, rating failed');
      }
   });


    }
```

I tried to do it like on this link:
[JavaScript to update MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060556/javascript-to-update-mysql)

Comment: Try this to debug - in Chrome, right click on the page -> Inspect Element -> click Network tab -> Look for the "Name" column -> execute ajax function -> look for votesystem.php in "Name" column -> if red, click on votesystem.php to find out error

Comment: You send a post request in javascript, but expect the parameters in get in php. Pls decide which method you want to use and stick to it!

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you are using $_GET variables in votesystem.php instead of $_POST variables. By adding `type: 'post'` to your ajax request you placed the parameters in the body of the http request which is accessed via $_POST

Comment: @ The One and Only ChemistryBlob i get this error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. I also changed get to post but still not working

Comment: @JimmyMorrisson Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: All i had to do was to load jQuery and change these get to POST. Thanks for help and your time

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do was to load jQuery and change these get to POST. Thanks for help and your time